# Loading javascript dependencies in popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am working on a .net project where I am creating a popup window using jquery as follows:

```
var newWindow = window.open("", id,    "resizable=1,status=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,top=0,left=0");
```

Then I am injecting the html document in it,

```
 newWindow.document.write("<!doctype html>" +
                          "<html>" +
                          "<head>" +
                          "<title>" + id + "</title>" +
                          "<link href='" + css + "' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />" +
                          "<script src= '/Scripts/d3.min.js' ><\/script/>" +
                          "<script src= '/Scripts/myScript.js' ><\/script/>" +
                          "</head>" +
                          "<body></body>" +
                          "</html>");
```

There is some code in myScript.js that uses d3 and draw some SVG stuff.
I call that draw function as follows:

```
$(newWindow.document).ready(function () {
   newWindow.DrawSvg();
}
```

However, it is throwing error that d3 is undefined.
It looks like, d3.min.js is not loading it still loading when I am calling that draw function.

My question is, how can I make sure that my child window is done finished loading the dependencies? it looks like $(newWindow.document).ready is not quite doing the trick!

**ADDITION:**
Interestingly, newWindow.DrawSvg() seems to work only in IE.
In firefox and chrome, DrawSvg return following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: newWindow.DrawSvg() is not a function
```

It looks like the javascript function is not available yet.
I tried to attach a timer to trigger that call after 500 ms, it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1125130/1585957).

Answer (score 1):

Try what this guy did: [Waiting for child window loading to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372022/waiting-for-child-window-loading-to-complete)

Basically:

```
var newWindow = window.open('child.html')
newWindow.addEventListener('load', newWindow.document.write(...), true);
newWindow.addEventListener('load', runAJAXhere, true);
```

etc.