# Info on DOM and web page lifecycle

Tags: asp.net, html, dom

I'm trying to find some good info on the ordering and events of a page...fundamentals.   (ordering of what loads and when ...DOM, javascript, no matter what language you're coding in)

Does anyone know a good reference I could take a look at?  I haven't found any good articles except for ASP.NET but I'm not looking for that specifically.  I want to look up how the DOM loads vs. order of JavaScript, etc. in the web overall.

I guess on the ASP.NET side I'd want to know though when rendering JS from code-behind how that mixes with the ordering of page load for the DOM.

Comment: It depends on the user agent, not ASP.

Comment: I'm mainly looking for non asp.net based information on how the web works in terms of DOM and how it loads...ordering with JS, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a good [JavaScript and HTML DOM
   Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp). You'll need to drill down into specific categories, but all the fundamentals are there.

There is another [post that discusses how the DOM is loaded and what happens when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307929/javascript-dom-load-events-execution-sequence-and-document-ready).

You may also find these (Yahoo) resources helpful in understanding page rendering performance:

- [High Performance Web Sites: Rule 5 – Put Stylesheets at the Top](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_4.html)
- [High Performance Web Sites: Rule 6 – Move Scripts to the Bottom](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_5.html)

(The general set of Yahoo's performance best-practices is here: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html.)