# page lifecycle in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the page life cycle in javascript?
  What are they?
How do they work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is bunch of information out here:

[JavaScript: DOM load events, execution sequence, and $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307929/javascript-dom-load-events-execution-sequence-and-document-ready)

[Info on DOM and web page lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320489/info-on-dom-and-web-page-lifecycle)

Javascript Execution order:
http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/exeorder.htm