# What is the very first event fired by an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm curious which event is fired first when using jQuery and jQuery Mobile.

Oddly enough, the first console output I get is `pagebeforecreate` then `document ready` and then `onload`.

I would like to know if any other events are being fired before these ones.

http://jsfiddle.net/yYGYe/2/

```
$('html').bind('pagebeforecreate',function(event) {
    console.log("pagebeforecreate");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("document ready");
});

window.onload = function(){
    console.log("onload");
};
```

Comment: May we know what for?

Comment: Is this specifically about jQuery Mobile? Because pagebeforecreate is not a standard event.

Comment: Might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523954/page-lifecycle-in-javascript

Comment: Why not do your things immediately without binding to an event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is a comprehensive visualisation of the jQuery mobile event model lifecycle, this diagram below is available in [Pro jQuery Mobile](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430239662) and [on the author's blog](http://bradbroulik.blogspot.co.nz/2011/12/jquery-mobile-events-diagram.html):

[image: jQuery Mobile Events Diagram - Brad Broulik]

Please remember that this is jQuery mobile specific. The list of native events is available [as part of the W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents), and the only one relevant to the document lifecycle is good old `load`.

Comment: DOM Level 3 introduced `DOMContentLoaded`, which fires before `load`. Also, this should be of interest: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/the-end.html.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I was debating whether or not to reference DOM L3 with it being a working draft not uniformly supported yet. You're absolutely right though, +1

Comment: I learned to assume that the HTML, CSS and DOM specifications will be in "working draft" state *forever*! Or *I* would have to wait forever. :)

Answer (score 4):

Your question and the actual thing you are asking are a bit different.

You ask what the first event fired is, but in the context you are asking if `pagebeforecreate` is the function to call if you want it to be the first event fired on the page.

If you read the jQuery Mobile documentation on that matter, it says that `pagebeforecreate` is called before any "widgets" are instantiated. So in that matter; everything you put in there will be called "before" all jQuery Mobile widgets, but is not per se the first event fired on the HTML page.

The first event fired on an HTML page is probably `document.readyState` being set as `uninitialized`, indicating your page is not ready loading yet. These are all ready-states;

- uninitialized (Has not started loading yet)
- loading (Is loading)
- interactive (Has loaded enough and the user can interact with it)
- complete (Fully loaded)

Comment: I believe there can be no listeners for _that_ `readystatechange`

Comment: `document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(this) { ... };` should work fine :) But correct me if I'm wrong. Don't have tools at hand to test.

Comment: Do you think I can register in time for that event? :-)

Comment: I mean, if the DOM didn't start loading, the page scripts didn't either.

Comment: @JanDvorak It's possible to intercept the "interactive" and "complete" states. See http://jsfiddle.net/Gs34Y/. In fact, onreadystatechange is what jQuery uses on oldIE to simulate DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: I noticed too it's `document.onreadystatechange = function () { console.log(document.readyState); }`, but it seems you can't get all states. Such irony? :P

Comment: I've Googled some on the first ready state  (`0`, `uninitialized`). It seems it is indeed skipped in most cases on a normal page load and probably can only be catched when loading external content, mostly when working with iFrames.