# How to run a script on page load

Tags: javascript, html

How I run a script tag when the page load using javascript.I need a on page load script execute code.i searched a lot of website for that code but i am not getting any relevant code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523954/page-lifecycle-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **onload** event : 
html binded to the body for example:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

or in javascript using addEventListener:

```
document.body.addEventListener("load", myFunc);
```

or

Try this:

```
<script>
   window.onload = function myFunc() {

       //do stuff

   }
</script>
```