# Control loading order of cross domain java scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a mobile web site wherein I pull in elements, using Xpath, from a parent site/domain and recreate them on a different domain. The trouble is that most of the elements that I pull in have inline styles attached by the Dojo JS framework. I tried removing these styles using this jQuery code

```
$('#elementID').removeAttr('style');
```

and it seems to work fine while the page is loading but once the page finishes loading the Dojo scripts attach the inline styles again. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035/javascript-load-order) that cross-domain scripts are loaded after the scripts of the site itself. Nonetheless, is there any way to control the script loading order?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Loader](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/).

> Google Loader Developer's Guide In order to use the Google APIs, you
>   must import them using the Google API loader in conjunction with the
>   API key. The loader allows you to easily import one or more APIs, and
>   specify additional settings (such as language, location, API version,
>   etc.) applicable to your needs. In addition to the basic loader
>   functionality, savvy developers can also use dynamic loading or
>   auto-loading to enhance the performance of your application.

Comment: Thanks but isn't this specific to Google APIs? I'm not using any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your script at the onload handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#elementID').removeAttr('style');
});
```

It executes after all other scripts are loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [defer attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script#attr-defer):

```
<script defer src="my-script.js"></script>
```

my-script.js:

```
  $('#elementID').removeAttr('style');
```